# Using the CHOMP motion planner in MoveIt!

Tags: motion-planning, moveit, kuka, moveit-setup-assistant, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use the CHOMP motion planner in MoveIt! for a KUKA lightweight arm (with Groovy). I have fairly limited experience with these tools and the tutorials for using CHOMP are limited to integration in [arm_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/arm_navigation/Tutorials) and the MoveIt! setup wizard doesn't provide an option for using CHOMP.

If somebody could explain how to modify the according MoveIt! launch files and maybe provide an example I would be grateful.

Thx,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81381/using-the-chomp-motion-planner-in-moveit!/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-11-11**:
Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
A functional version of Chomp has been merged into kinetic [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/kinetic-devel/moveit_planners/chomp).  Feel free to make a Pull Request to fix issues or document the code.  Thanks

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-10-31**:
A very basic tutorial has been started here: https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_tutorials/blob/2d7d4a9a1e7c1209c26ffe4be3a049751c8eed4c/doc/chomp_interface_tutorial.rst

It will be found on http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/ once the buildfarm refreshes.